# Instantiating a class that is in a sparate file?

Tags: java, c++, class, instantiation

So I'm used to Java but I'm learning C++ and the big thing for me is I like to create seperate classes for a lot of stuff. And keep those classes in their own seperate files, just like Java. But in java I would access another class by saying Class.method(arguments); how do I do this in C++?

Here is the code specifically

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Vector2f a = new Vector2f(2.0f, 4.0f);

    std::cout << "Magnitude :" << mod(a);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the Class file

```
class Vector2f{ 

    private:

        float _x;
        float _y;

    public:

        //Constructor
        void Vector2f(float x, float y){

            _x = x;
            _y = y;
        }

        //Vector Operations

        float dot(Vector2f a, Vector2f b){

            return (a.getX()*b.getX()) + (a.getY()*b.getY());
        }

        float mod(Vector2f a){

            return sqrt((a.getX()*a.getX())+(a.getY()*a.getY()));
        }


        //Getters and Setters

        void setX(float x){
            _x = x;
        }
        void setY(float y){
            _y = y;
        }
        float getX(){
            return _x;
        }
        float getY(){
            return _y;
        }

};
```

Why doesnt this work? should just create an instance of the vector class??

Comment: There is no such thing a "class file" in C++. There are header files, which contain type and function definitions, and source files, which contain the actual code.

Comment: `Vector2f a = new Vector2f(2.0f, 4.0f);` This doesn't compile. You mean `Vector2f a(2.0f, 4.0f);` There is no need for new

Comment: @NeilKirk: And for templates / inline functions, both are in the header file.

Comment: First things first: C++ is not Java. Most Java idioms are atrocious anti-patterns in C++. Anyway, OO-dogmatic style faux-encapsulation is bad in either camp.

Comment: So a function in another file can be used as if it were in the main file but a class cant -_-?

Comment: @AndrewGraham, You would still need a header file that *declared* the function even if the `cpp` file *defined* the function.

Comment: In C and C++, declaration and definition are not equivalent, while to the best of my knowledge, they always happen together in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `void` in front of your constructor. Your constructor could be constructed like this:

```
Vector2f(float x, float y){

    _x = x;
    _y = y;
}
```

For function inside the class, you don't have to create another parameter for its. So your functions could be:

```
float dot(Vector2f b){

    return (getX()*b.getX()) + (getY()*b.getY());
}

float mod(){

    return sqrt((getX()*getX()) + (getY()*getY()));
}
```

Same thing with the other function.

To access the function inside a class. You do this: className.functionName();
You don't have to use the keyword `new` to create a new instance. What `new` does is it will create your object inside heap and if you use `new` to create an object, you have to use `delete` after you've done with it. Otherwise, it will cause leak memory. In main, you could just do like this:

```
int main()
{
    Vector2f a(2.0f, 4.0f);
    std::cout << "Magnitude :" << a.mod() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you are defining all methods inline, which you may or may not have intended.

Second, if you want to access `Vector2f` from `main.cpp`, you will have to `#include` the header file that defines the class.

Without this `#include`, the compiler does see the class and method declarations, so will complain about you trying to instantiate a class that it does not know about.

Third, you are using `new`, which returns a pointer, so you will need to declare your variable as a pointer type.

```
Vector2f* a = new Vector2f(2.0f, 4.0f);
```

Further, if you create an object on the heap using `new`, you should `delete` it when you are done using it.

```
delete a;
```

Alternately, if you want to instantiate on the stack (instead of the heap), you can do as the other answer suggests.

```
Vector2f a(2.0f, 4.0f);
```

Fourth, you have a bunch of compile errors in your class, which you probably want to fix before trying to instantiate the object. For example, **constructors do not return void**, even in Java.